Two level ActiveRecord query
Factory has_many Worker through JobRole, for example.
factory model:
has_many :workers, through: :job_roles

worker model:
has_many :job_roles
has_many :factories, through: :job_roles

job_role model:
belongs_to :worker
belongs_to :factory

query:
factory.job_roles.where(heavy_lifting:true, sensitive_area: false).workers.where.not(confirmed_at:nil).pluck(:work_capacity)

The first .where query is an ActiveRelation, calling .workers on it fails.
I need pull the work_capacity of the workers who have specific job_roles within a factory.
Any way to do this other than looping through the first query to put the worker's work capacity in an array?
i.e.:
applicable_job roles = factory.job_roles.where(heavy_lifting:true, sensitive_area: false)

work_capacities = []

applicable_job_roles.each do |job_role|
 if job_role.confirmed_at != nil
 work_capacities << job_role.work_capacity
end


please show the relationships between the Factory, JobRole, and Worker models

now updated, thank you

factory.workers.where.not(confirmed_at:nil).where(job_roles: {heavy_lifting:true, sensitive_area: false}).pluck(:work_capacity)


unfortunately, NoMethodError: undefined method `job_roles' for main:Object ...  if I just do factory.workers.job_roles it gives me NoMethodError: undefined method `job_roles' for #<Worker::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x0056504e224008>

@daveasdf_2 should be fixed now. Was missing a : after job_roles

Right. Nice, I appreciate that, thank you. Never seen a where like that, it's going in the notebook

While correct this answer would greatly benefit from a written explanation

really? Does this answer work? I felt sure you'd need a join clause. Have you confirmed it?

@LesNightingill calling factory.workers already took care of the join clause since the association is through job_roles, so you do not need to re-include it

@AbM the join I was thinking of was job_roles, but I guess if it's working, I must be wrong... not even the first time today lol

Confirmed, works

@LesNightingill because workers is a "through relationship" the job roles table join is required i.e. factories -> job_roles -> workers. So anytime Factory#workers is called the job_roles table will be present.
